# Asp.Net Core DataProtection between Web Apps not working on Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have two WebApps on Azure running on the Free tier service plan. There's a scenario where I generate an Identity reset password token from WebApp A and use it in the WebApp B.

In my Startup.cs I have the DataProtection setup as follows in the ConfigureServices method:

```
services.AddDataProtection().SetApplicationName("appname");
```

It runs fine locally, but when I try to reset the password in this scenario I get an Invalid Token error message on Azure.

I'm running ASP.NET Core 2.1 with Identity Core. Is there any Azure restriction for this DataProtection setup or something to do with the free tier service plan?

Thanks!

Comment: I think the Azure Free Tier should have full access to the Data Protection API. 
 Looking at the Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-2.2#setapplicationname), there seem to be some very explicit instructions to be SURE you are using the exact same Data Protection API stack across the apps.  So, I have to ask... Are we 100% sure that both WebApp A and WebApp B are using the identical Data Protection API?

Comment: @TroyWitthoeft , both are configured exact like the code I posted before, and both projects have the Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection assembly on version 2.1.1. Would anything else needed to be configured?

Comment: @Markissimo Are you using IdentityServer? Then you can use grant proxy token delegation to use for API B, from API A. If you are using simple oauth implementation, then two servers contains who different instances of IS database (or in-memory) and unaware of each other tokens

Comment: @Markissimo How did you *configure* data protection? The default settings are [suitable for a single machine only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-2.2). You won't be able to use tokens across web apps unless they run on the *same* machine. The reason is that data protection services use the machine's encryption key for encryption by default

Comment: @Markissimo this isn't specific to Azure either. The same problem occures in any ASP.NET web farm. That's why [the machine key has to be configured on all servers in a farm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ff649308(v=pandp.10)#paght000007_webfarmdeploymentconsiderations)

Comment: So, I gave up trying to make this work, so I implemented my own TokenProvider, using a common database between the webapps to validate the reset password token. So I won't be able to test the suggestions. Anyway many of those are good information, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to share cookie between application 
ASP.Net core ASP.net application try this article
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-2.2`

```
services.AddDataProtection()
    .PersistKeysToFileSystem(GetKeyRingDirInfo())
    .SetApplicationName("SharedCookieApp");

services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => {
    options.Cookie.Name = ".AspNet.SharedCookie";
});`
```

Comment: check domain name that must be different. options.Cookie.Domain = ".contoso.com";

Answer (score 0):

There are some differences in how the APS.NET (Core) works on the IIS server and on the Azure Web Apps. While it is not exactly the restriction (you would get some error in that case), some things technically don't work. As far as I have read you don't have your own virtual server in Web Apps, but rather there is a pool of servers where at any time any server can be dedicated to your task. This makes some of the things not working properly and if you detected the difference it is almost certainly due to this.

Also of note, testing if it is limited to the free tier will cost you less than 1$, so it is probably better idea to test that than to ask it, just I am not aware of any API limitations of the free tier.